# Categorizing & Legend with two attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-2.8

On a Layer, preferably a point, I categorized its style. So after categorizing using attribute1, I would like to show the legends using attribute2. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly that you want to show in the legend just field 2 and remove field 1 in the map composer you can do the following:

[image]

- Uncheck "Auto update" from the legend items after adding the legend
- Select each item in Field 1 and press on the *Red Minus*

This is the final output to keep only the Field 2 information in the legend.

[image]

However, if you want to categorize Field 2 based on Field 1, in other words refine the values in Field 1, then you need to use Rule-based styling, as you can see below:

[image]

1. Select Rule-based from drop-down menu
2. Define the rule based on the Field 1 (desired field). In the example below, I used a field named River to show two values: "River = 0" and "River" = 1
3. Refine the taget field by right-click and select `Add category to rule` or `Add range to rule` depending on the way of styling. In this example, I selected `Add category to rule`, and I chose Field 2 named "I" to show its values within category "River" = 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1. Prepare the styling with categories for field 1;
2. Select Lock layers and lock styles for layers in the map (item properties):
   [image: Lock styles]
3. Go back to the main window (not composer) and change the style of your layer to have categories for field 2.

The legend will update in the print composer, but not the map.
Cheers,